# Can I make a folder of forms and views and use an __init__.py file like models and test?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I would like to keep my views and forms separate, just like you can with models. Are you able to make a directory of views and forms, and if so, what goes in the **init**.py files for each.

---

Update:

I made my folders, but I keep getting errors. Here's all my code info:

myproject structure (abbreviated):

```
myproject/
    myproject/
    name/
        forms/
            __init__.py
            name_form.py
        models/
            __init__.py
            name_model.py
        urls.py
        views/
            __init__.py
            name_view.py
```

models/**init**.py

```
from .name_model import Name
```

models/name_model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Name(models.Model):
    ...
```

`forms/__init__.py` and `views/__init__.py` are blank files.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from name.views import name_view


app_name = 'name'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.name_view, name='name-view'),
]
```

forms/name_form.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput


from name.models import Name


class NameForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Name
```

views/name_view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


from name.forms import NameForm


def name_view(request):
    ...
```

I run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` in the terminal and get:

```
/myproject/name/views/name_view.py", line 4, in <module>
    from name.forms import NameForm
ImportError: cannot import name 'NameForm'
```

Thinking you can't make a `ModelForm` without a `model`, I run `python3 manage.py migrate` and get the same error.

I created a project to isolate this issue. Without the folders it worked, unless I messed up my original code trying to get this to work.

Comment: You can put them wherever you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a folder for your views and a folder for your forms wherever you want them to be and put an empty `__init__.py` file into each folder. The purpose of the `__init__.py` file is to tell python to treat the folder as a module. Then make your `views.py` file and your `forms.py` file in their respective directories and now you can do...

```
from myproject.path.to.views import MyView
from myproject.path.to.forms import MyForm
```

...as if it were any other module. Which it is.

Comment: I tried to do that, and I thought it initially worked, but it's actually not working. If have view.py and forms.py files, it works. But when I made a folder 'views' with a file 'name_view.py', it gives me an attribute error and can't find the view.

Comment: `from myproject.path.to.name_view import MyView`? The module itself has the same name as the file.

Comment: I had to add from .name_form import NameForm and the same for the views equivalent in the init.py files